# How to fix value not inserted to database using ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

My form data value isn't inserting to my database after submit. before I'm setting **ckEditor** post data using ajax and it succeeds, but I get an error from a different input after that. The error I get is `Undefined index` for all of my input. If I add `if (issest($_POST["submit"]))`, all errors disappear but data is not sent to the database. Can you help me? here is my code:

```
  <form id="addpostForm" class="" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputPostTitle" class="sr-only">Title</label>
      <input name="post_title" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPostTitle" placeholder="Title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputEditor" class="sr-only">Content</label>
      <textarea name="post_content" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEditor"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputTags">Tags</label>
      <input name="tags" type="text" id="inputTags" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="Separate tags with (,) commas">
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="buttonAddPost">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#buttonAddPost').click(function(){
      //var formData = new FormData($('#addpostForm')[0]);
      var ckEditor = CKEDITOR.instances.inputEditor.getData();
      formData = $("#addpostForm").serialize + '&ckEditor=' + encodeURIComponent(ckEditor);
      //alert(ckEditor);
      //formData.append("post_content", ckEditor);

      $.ajax({
        url: 'modules/post/add.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(resAddPost){
          if(resAddPost == 'ok'){
            $.bootstrapGrowl('Form data submitted successfully.', {type: 'success'});
          }else{
            $.bootstrapGrowl('Some problem occurred, please try again.', {type: 'danger'});
          }
          console.log(resAddPost);
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
          console.log(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Php:

```
<?php include "../../../_includes/config.php"; ?>
<?php
include "../../data/prettyurl.php";
session_start();
$post_id = time();
$post_title = $_POST['post_title'];
$post_content = $_POST['post_content'];
$post_added = date('Y-m-d');
$post_author = $_SESSION['SES_LOGIN']['user_display'];
$tags = explode(",", $_POST['tags']);
$post_title = trim($post_title);
$post_title_result = $post_title;
if($post_title_result){
  $post_slug = pretty_url($post_title);
  $post_title_data = $post_title;
}
$post_slug2 = $post_slug;
$query_check_post_slug = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_posts WHERE post_slug LIKE '".$post_slug."%'") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_check_post_slug)){
  $post_slugs[] = $row['post_slug'];
  if(mysql_num_rows($query_check_post_slug) !== 0 && in_array($post_slug, $post_slugs)){
    $max = 0;
    $post_slug = $post_slug2;
    while(in_array(($post_slug.'-'.++$max), $post_slugs));
    $post_slug .= '-'.$max;
  }
}

$query_insert_post = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_posts (post_id, post_title, post_content, post_added, post_author, post_slug) VALUES ('$post_id', '$post_title', '$post_content', '$post_added', '$post_author', '$post_slug')") or die(mysql_error());
foreach($tags as $tag){
  $tag_id = "Tag-".$tag;
  $query_insert_tags = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_tags (tag_id, tag) VALUES ('$tag_id', '$tag')") or die(mysql_error());
  $query_insert_tag_posts = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_tag_posts (post_id, tag_id) VALUES ('$post_id', '$tag_id')") or die(mysql_error());
}
if($query_insert_post){
  echo "ok";
}else{
  echo "err";
}
?>
```

My ckEditor replace ID "inputEditor".

Comment: Show some more of that PHP code - the query, connection, and so on are highly relevant.

Comment: There will be no `$_POST['post_content']`, because you send different values in the `data`.

Comment: Use the Network tab of the console to see what parameters are being sent to the server.

Comment: i show my php code, reload page!

Comment: You should convert from the `mysql_XXX` functions to PDO or mysqli. The mysql extension has been deprecated for many years, and is completely removed in PHP 7. You should then learn to write prepared statements with parameters to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: yes, I will change, I am still in the learning stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
data: formData + '&ckEditor=' + ckEditor,
```

`formData` is not a string, you can't concatenate it.

Instead, you should do:

```
formData.append('ckEditor', ckeditor);
```

before `$.ajax`.

Then in the PHP use `$_POST['ckEditor']` to get this field.

You can also use serialized data like this:

```
formData = $("#addpostForm").serialize() + '&ckEditor=' + encodeURIComponent(ckEditor);
```

If you do this, you shouldn't use `contentType: false`.

Comment: i do this before formData.append("post_content", ckEditor); and data: $('#addpostForm').serialize() + '&ckEditor=' + ckEditor, but same error

Comment: `&ckEditor=` means you want it to be in `$_POST['ckEditor']`. Why are you calling it `post_content` when you call `.append()`?

Comment: i dont know too, u just try random code after searching. so like this if i use serialize code?
var ckEditor = CKEDITOR.instances.inputEditor.getData();
data: $('#addpostForm').serialize() + '&post_content=' + ckEditor,

Comment: Don't "try random code after searching", that's cargo-cult programming. You need to understand how the code works. It generally won't do exactly what you need, you need to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: ya i try to understand how code work, but i dont know basic code of them, so i just searching and add to my code like that.
data: $('#addpostForm').serialize() + '&post_content=' + encodeURIComponent(ckEditor); like this?

Comment: i delete var formData = new FormData($('#addpostForm')[0]); and //formData.append("post_content", ckEditor); only: var ckEditor = CKEDITOR.instances.inputEditor.getData(); and formData = $("#addpostForm").serialize + '&ckEditor=' + encodeURIComponent(ckEditor);
$.ajax: data: formData, i try submit Undefined index post_title, post_content, and more error.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo, I forgot the `()` after `serialize`.

Comment: should i change to $_POST['ckEditor'];? because,  now only post_content not inserted to db

Comment: Yes, of course. It has to match the name in the form data.

Comment: status: echo ok

Comment: if like that, what is the function of name="post_content" on input form?

Comment: That's the name of the regular for field. But you're getting the data from ckEditor.

Comment: oh, what if i delete it? i think nothing error. or not?

Answer (score 0):

Please correct the key name you have added in $_POST function. Like this

You send data with : data: formData + '&ckEditor=' + ckEditor,

So why you get it in : $_POST['post_content'];

You need to try it as $_POST['ckEditor'];

Comment: so i can change ...&ckEditor=... to &post_content? i show my php code, u can refresh